# Как бороться с UDP flood с моего сервера?

Tags: ubuntu

С помощью tshark записал этой ночью лог размером 1,4 Гб. У хостинг-провайдера в статистике вижу 5 Гб исходящего трафика. В логе есть много вот такого:

```
25513 18487.338178000 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -> 213.248.70.74 UDP 45 Source port: 42835  Destination port: http
```

То есть мой сервер кого-то очень задолбал... Как пресечь эти атаки?

**UPDATE**

Сегодня ночью сервер отослал очередные 5 Гб в неизвестном направлении. Я в этот раз не логировал. Все это несмотря на активное правило `iptables`, упомянутое в ответе ниже. Впрочем, именно это и ожидалось. Заблокировать полностью исходящий UDP трафик не получится, поскольку перестает работать часть приложения (важная). Я так понимаю, что раз атаки идут на разные адреса, значит есть внешнее управление этим зловредным скриптом, соответственно, можно поискать входящий трафик. Очень меня расстраивает, что я не могу запустить `auditctl`, из-за этого я даже не знаю, что дальше делать. Единственный вариант сидеть всю ночь и тыкать `netstat`, но это, конечно, не наш метод. 
И еще, непонятно мне, на каком уровне эта уязвимость? Ubuntu, Ruby, Rails, Nginx, Gems, или скрипты моего приложения (возможноб я в бессознательном состоянии что-то написал?).

**UPDATE2**
Очередные 13 Гб трафика, однако, в логе сделаном с помощью `netstat` нет udp... Но я записывал еще и tcp. Во время атаки соединений больше, кое что не нравится. Помогите проанализировать.
Мне вот это странно, особенно вторая строчка, поскольку стоит `DenyHosts`, который ограничен моим IP:

`udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:39229           0.0.0.0:*                           24944/ssh.a`

`tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:49536     89.248.162.167:7878     ESTABLISHED 23459/ssh.a`

`raw   133393      0 0.0.0.0:6               0.0.0.0:*               7           25938/ssh.a`

Ну и полный отрывок лога во время атаки:

```
Thu Jan 21 11:45:01 EST 2016
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      542/redis-server *:
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:43696         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      944/public (product
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      843/passenger-stand
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      458/sshd        
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:42570     87.240.131.97:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:60066     87.240.131.120:443      TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45818         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED 487/sidekiq 4.0.1 c
tcp        0      1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:43675     87.240.131.119:443      SYN_SENT    487/sidekiq 4.0.1 c
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:45332     87.240.131.118:443      TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:38405     87.240.131.120:443      TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:45886     95.213.10.67:443        TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:45881         ESTABLISHED 542/redis-server *:
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:42159         127.0.0.1:6379          TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:44901     87.240.131.120:443      TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:60627     87.240.131.119:443      TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:49536     89.248.162.167:7878     ESTABLISHED 23459/ssh.a     
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:42830     87.240.131.119:443      TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:60234     95.213.10.67:443        TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:35717     87.240.131.120:443      TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:22        yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:52071      ESTABLISHED 1124/3          
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56170     87.240.131.120:443      TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:43299         127.0.0.1:6379          TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:45346     87.240.131.97:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:33201     87.240.131.120:443      TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:45818         ESTABLISHED 542/redis-server *:
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34806         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED 944/public (product
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:54722     87.240.131.97:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45881         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED 487/sidekiq 4.0.1 c
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:57360     87.240.131.120:443      TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:38655     87.240.131.120:443      TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:54377         ESTABLISHED 542/redis-server *:
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:38904     87.240.131.97:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:50461     87.240.131.97:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:54377         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED 487/sidekiq 4.0.1 c
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:39521     87.240.131.120:443      TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:34806         ESTABLISHED 542/redis-server *:
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:34898     87.240.131.120:443      TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:51598     87.240.131.118:443      TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:44621     87.240.131.120:443      TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:33190     87.240.131.119:443      TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp6       0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN      542/redis-server *:
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      458/sshd        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:39229           0.0.0.0:*                           24944/ssh.a     
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name    Path
unix  7      [ ]         DGRAM                    1210390272 369/rsyslogd        /dev/log
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1210385422 192/dbus-daemon     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1210378151 1/init              @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1210488639 944/public (product /tmp/passenger.N2QiE2U/apps.s/ruby.oHNcRoqeHnLrDbPuCKtAh4PmQbCoM1s3BGyjQoYwXLvdYpxR2zu4gb2JFxkTaQG
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     1210385280 180/systemd-udevd   /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1210395584 586/saslauthd       /var/run/saslauthd/mux
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1210406327 817/Passenger watch /tmp/passenger.N2QiE2U/agents.s/watchdog_api
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1210406375 820/Passenger core  /tmp/passenger.N2QiE2U/agents.s/core
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1210406378 820/Passenger core  /tmp/passenger.N2QiE2U/agents.s/core_api
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1210406659 827/Passenger ust-r /tmp/passenger.N2QiE2U/agents.s/ust_router
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1210406663 827/Passenger ust-r /tmp/passenger.N2QiE2U/agents.s/ust_router_api
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    1395302358 24955/sudo          
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1395302346 24955/sudo          
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    1395301812 24950/CRON          
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    1210925643 1124/3              
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210486288 944/public (product /tmp/passenger.N2QiE2U/apps.s/preloader.1pwgbp8
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210486279 820/Passenger core  
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210424660 820/Passenger core  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210406746 843/passenger-stand 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210406745 843/passenger-stand 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210406488 827/Passenger ust-r 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210406487 817/Passenger watch 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210406332 820/Passenger core  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210406331 817/Passenger watch 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210405961 817/Passenger watch 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210405960 843/passenger-stand 
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    1210395582 586/saslauthd       
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    1210393315 453/xinetd          
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210388361 192/dbus-daemon     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210388359 274/systemd-logind  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210387404 192/dbus-daemon     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210387401 1/init              
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    1210385979 180/systemd-udevd   
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    1210385978 180/systemd-udevd   
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210385964 192/dbus-daemon     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210385963 192/dbus-daemon     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210388307 1/init              @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210385958 502/upstart-socket- 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210387946 1/init              @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210385956 501/upstart-file-br 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210384114 1/init              @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210383966 150/upstart-udev-br 
Thu Jan 21 11:50:01 EST 2016
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      542/redis-server *:
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:43696         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      944/public (product
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      843/passenger-stand
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      458/sshd        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45818         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED 487/sidekiq 4.0.1 c
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:45881         ESTABLISHED 542/redis-server *:
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:38615     87.240.131.120:443      TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:49536     89.248.162.167:7878     ESTABLISHED 23459/ssh.a     
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:22        yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:52071      ESTABLISHED 1124/3          
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:41462     87.240.131.99:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:45818         ESTABLISHED 542/redis-server *:
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:38871     87.240.131.99:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34806         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED 944/public (product
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:48582     95.213.11.113:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45881         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED 487/sidekiq 4.0.1 c
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:54377         ESTABLISHED 542/redis-server *:
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:54377         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED 487/sidekiq 4.0.1 c
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:54592     87.240.131.97:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:34806         ESTABLISHED 542/redis-server *:
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:36675     87.240.131.99:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp6       0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN      542/redis-server *:
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      458/sshd        
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name    Path
unix  9      [ ]         DGRAM                    1210390272 369/rsyslogd        /dev/log
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1210385422 192/dbus-daemon     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1210378151 1/init              @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1210488639 944/public (product /tmp/passenger.N2QiE2U/apps.s/ruby.oHNcRoqeHnLrDbPuCKtAh4PmQbCoM1s3BGyjQoYwXLvdYpxR2zu4gb2JFxkTaQG
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     1210385280 180/systemd-udevd   /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1210395584 586/saslauthd       /var/run/saslauthd/mux
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1210406327 817/Passenger watch /tmp/passenger.N2QiE2U/agents.s/watchdog_api
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1210406375 820/Passenger core  /tmp/passenger.N2QiE2U/agents.s/core
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1210406378 820/Passenger core  /tmp/passenger.N2QiE2U/agents.s/core_api
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1210406659 827/Passenger ust-r /tmp/passenger.N2QiE2U/agents.s/ust_router
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1210406663 827/Passenger ust-r /tmp/passenger.N2QiE2U/agents.s/ust_router_api
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    1396939951 25394/sudo          
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1396939860 25394/sudo          
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    1396937291 25381/CRON          
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    1396937230 25382/CRON          
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    1396936904 25379/CRON          
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    1210925643 1124/3              
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210486288 944/public (product /tmp/passenger.N2QiE2U/apps.s/preloader.1pwgbp8
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210486279 820/Passenger core  
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210424660 820/Passenger core  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210406746 843/passenger-stand 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210406745 843/passenger-stand 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210406488 827/Passenger ust-r 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210406487 817/Passenger watch 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210406332 820/Passenger core  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210406331 817/Passenger watch 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210405961 817/Passenger watch 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210405960 843/passenger-stand 
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    1210395582 586/saslauthd       
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    1210393315 453/xinetd          
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210388361 192/dbus-daemon     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210388359 274/systemd-logind  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210387404 192/dbus-daemon     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210387401 1/init              
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    1210385979 180/systemd-udevd   
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    1210385978 180/systemd-udevd   
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210385964 192/dbus-daemon     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210385963 192/dbus-daemon     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210388307 1/init              @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210385958 502/upstart-socket- 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210387946 1/init              @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210385956 501/upstart-file-br 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210384114 1/init              @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210383966 150/upstart-udev-br 
Thu Jan 21 11:55:01 EST 2016
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      542/redis-server *:
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:43696         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      944/public (product
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      843/passenger-stand
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      458/sshd        
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:45656     87.240.131.97:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45818         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED 487/sidekiq 4.0.1 c
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:45881         ESTABLISHED 542/redis-server *:
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:35404     87.240.131.119:443      TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:45411     95.213.11.113:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:48676     95.213.11.113:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:57493         127.0.0.1:6379          TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56422     95.213.10.67:443        TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:46582     87.240.131.99:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:58680         127.0.0.1:6379          TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:49536     89.248.162.167:7878     ESTABLISHED 23459/ssh.a     
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:60497     95.213.11.113:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:34583     87.240.131.99:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:22        yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:52071      ESTABLISHED 1124/3          
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:59509     87.240.131.99:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:51015     87.240.131.119:443      TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:34454     87.240.131.97:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:57932     87.240.131.99:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:43584     95.213.11.113:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:38269     95.213.11.113:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:58156     87.240.131.97:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:45818         ESTABLISHED 542/redis-server *:
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:50815     95.213.11.113:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34806         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED 944/public (product
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45881         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED 487/sidekiq 4.0.1 c
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:54377         ESTABLISHED 542/redis-server *:
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:54377         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED 487/sidekiq 4.0.1 c
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:22        185.130.5.246:40561     ESTABLISHED 25932/sshd: [accept
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:53227     87.240.131.97:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:34806         ESTABLISHED 542/redis-server *:
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:46258     95.213.10.67:443        TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp6       0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN      542/redis-server *:
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      458/sshd        
raw   133393      0 0.0.0.0:6               0.0.0.0:*               7           25938/ssh.a     
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name    Path
unix  7      [ ]         DGRAM                    1210390272 369/rsyslogd        /dev/log
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1210385422 192/dbus-daemon     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1210378151 1/init              @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1210488639 944/public (product /tmp/passenger.N2QiE2U/apps.s/ruby.oHNcRoqeHnLrDbPuCKtAh4PmQbCoM1s3BGyjQoYwXLvdYpxR2zu4gb2JFxkTaQG
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     1210385280 180/systemd-udevd   /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1210395584 586/saslauthd       /var/run/saslauthd/mux
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1210406327 817/Passenger watch /tmp/passenger.N2QiE2U/agents.s/watchdog_api
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1210406375 820/Passenger core  /tmp/passenger.N2QiE2U/agents.s/core
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1210406378 820/Passenger core  /tmp/passenger.N2QiE2U/agents.s/core_api
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1210406659 827/Passenger ust-r /tmp/passenger.N2QiE2U/agents.s/ust_router
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1210406663 827/Passenger ust-r /tmp/passenger.N2QiE2U/agents.s/ust_router_api
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    1398567677 25963/sudo          
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1398567675 25963/sudo          
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    1398567084 25958/CRON          
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1398277376 25932/sshd: [accept 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1398277375 25935/sshd: [net]   
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    1210925643 1124/3              
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210486288 944/public (product /tmp/passenger.N2QiE2U/apps.s/preloader.1pwgbp8
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210486279 820/Passenger core  
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210424660 820/Passenger core  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210406746 843/passenger-stand 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210406745 843/passenger-stand 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210406488 827/Passenger ust-r 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210406487 817/Passenger watch 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210406332 820/Passenger core  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210406331 817/Passenger watch 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210405961 817/Passenger watch 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210405960 843/passenger-stand 
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    1210395582 586/saslauthd       
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    1210393315 453/xinetd          
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210388361 192/dbus-daemon     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210388359 274/systemd-logind  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210387404 192/dbus-daemon     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210387401 1/init              
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    1210385979 180/systemd-udevd   
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    1210385978 180/systemd-udevd   
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210385964 192/dbus-daemon     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210385963 192/dbus-daemon     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210388307 1/init              @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210385958 502/upstart-socket- 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210387946 1/init              @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210385956 501/upstart-file-br 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210384114 1/init              @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1210383966 150/upstart-udev-br 
Thu Jan 21 12:00:01 EST 2016
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      542/redis-server *:
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:43696         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      944/public (product
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      843/passenger-stand
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      458/sshd        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45818         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED 487/sidekiq 4.0.1 c
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:45881         ESTABLISHED 542/redis-server *:
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:43411     87.240.131.119:443      TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:52648     87.240.131.99:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:49536     89.248.162.167:7878     ESTABLISHED 23459/ssh.a     
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:22        yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:52071      ESTABLISHED 1124/3          
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:51809     87.240.131.99:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:45818         ESTABLISHED 542/redis-server *:
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34806         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED 944/public (product
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45881         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED 487/sidekiq 4.0.1 c
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:54377         ESTABLISHED 542/redis-server *:
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:60075     95.213.11.113:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:54377         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED 487/sidekiq 4.0.1 c
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:34806         ESTABLISHED 542/redis-server *:
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56281     87.240.131.99:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:53151     95.213.11.113:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:48683     87.240.131.99:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp6       0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN      542/redis-server *:
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      458/sshd        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:34806           0.0.0.0:*                           26495/ssh.a
```

Comment: `netstat -np | grep udp` покажет вам все процессы, использующие udp. Среди них находите ту, что использует порты что вы видите tshark

Comment: @Mike netstat отличная вещь, но я должен им воспользоваться во время атаки. Однако, когда происходят атаки у меня 1-5 утра.... Можно, конечно, посидеть, потыкать, но как-то не айс. Хотя если не найду решения, то именно так и буду делать.

Comment: Можно в cron добавить задачу, которая будет скажем раз в 10 мин. писать netstat в файл

Comment: не силен я в linux скриптах. не подскажите решение? хотя уже разобрался!

Comment: можно итоговый результат?

Comment: @nobilik  Запись для /etc/crontabs или где он у вас там: `*/5 * * * * root netstat -np | grep udp >/var/log/netstats/\`date "+%F_%H-%M"\``  Каталог /var/log/netstats создать заранее. ну или в другое место положите, как удобнее. `*/5` означает раз в 5 минут, увеличте по необходимости, что бы не особо много файлов создавало

Comment: @АлексейПрисяжный я с написанием скрипта разобрался) По поимке зверя - обязательно поделюсь

Comment: @Mike я немного иначе сделал `*/5 * * * * date >> /var/log/netstat_udp.log & sudo netstat -napu >> /var/log/netstat_udp.log`

Comment: @nobilik только `&` на `&&` замените.

Comment: @АлексейПрисяжный не совсем результат, но посмотрите апдейт

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101370/ru484385flood предлагаю онлайн

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну тут в любом случае работать по трём направлениям:

1. Заблокировать отправку (iptables?)
   iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -d 213.248.70.74 -j DROP
   не забудьте перестраховаться от выстрела в ногу :), ну там запланируйте ребут через НН минут и не сохраняйте правило.
2. Найти и прибить паршивца.
   [неплохой](https://serverfault.com/questions/192893/how-i-can-identify-which-process-is-making-udp-traffic-on-linux) рецепт со смежного сайта, с использованием auditd (apt-get install auditd)
   auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b64 -F a0=2 -F a1=2 -S socket -k SOCKET
   добавляем логирование сокетов вообще, а дальше смотрим по логу
   ausearch -i -ts today -k SOCKET
   и ищем pid=, по нему ищем автора и докапываемся, откуда оно взялось. Не забываем потом отключить эту ресурсоемкую операцию.
3. Найти дырку, откуда вообще всё пролезло, чтоб не повторили в будущем
   тут разбираться Вам по месту.

Comment: Отлично, сейчас займусь! Можете навести на мысли, как дырку искать?

Comment: Виноват, погорячился. Прокомментировал не дочитав.

Comment: @nobilik, можно записывать, например, [uid отправителя пакетов](http://superuser.com/q/34782/454489). правда, подозреваю, что, скорее всего, это будет uid пользователя, от имени которого работает ваш http-сервер.

Comment: У меня почему то не запускается демон аудита... За совет спасибо

Comment: система какая? установился успешно? С каким сообщением (в лог?) не запускает? Поскольку там модуль ядра, может помочь перезагрузка

Comment: @АлексейПрисяжный ubuntu 14.04. перегружал. установка ок. `type=DAEMON_START msg=audit(1453273260.149:3110): auditd start, ver=2.3.2 format=raw kernel=2.6.32 auid=0 pid=3512 res=success
type=DAEMON_ABORT msg=audit(1453273260.151:3111): auditd error halt, auid=0 pid=3512 res=failed`

Comment: я более [подробно](http://serverfault.com/questions/750546/cant-start-auditctl-in-ubuntu-14-04) на смежном форуме про логи написал

Comment: [тут](http://kb.odin.com/en/121587) народ пишет, что использование `audit` в контейнере невозможно